# RxJS Looking for something like "delayUntil"

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have two functions, one returns `observableA` and one `observableB`. I want the getter as well as the subscription of `observableB` to delay until `observableA` is complete (but it can also be the case then when I’m subscribing to `observableB`, `observableA` is already completed).

I’ve already tried to use `pipe` and `skipUntil` but unfortunately this only prevents the execution and doesn’t delays it if `observableA` is not completed yet.

```js
functionA() {
  this.observableA$ = getObservableA()
  this.observableA$.subscribe(_ => {
    // A: This line should execute *before* line B
  })
}

functionB() {
  this.observableB$ = getObservableB()  // This getter should execute *after* line A
  this.observableB$.subscribe(_ => {
    // B: This line should execute *after* line A
  })
}

// Two functions are called independently
functionA()
functionB()
```

Would be great to find a very RxJS-ish way :)

---

**Update 1: The problem with `concat`:**
As noted both functions are called independently which would result in a double-execution of `observableA$` when using `concat` like suggested. Also the subscription in `functionB` would be executed twice what I don't want.

```js
functionA() {
  this.observableA$ = getObservableA()
  this.observableA$.subscribe(_ => {
    // A: This line should execute *before* line B
  })
}

functionB() {
  Observable.concat(
    this.observableA$,  // I get executed once again :(
    Observable.defer(() => getObservableB())  // To prevent earlier execution
  ).subscribe(() => {
    // B: This line should execute *after* line A
    console.log("I'm logged twice, once for each observable :(")
  })
}

// Two functions are called independently
functionA()
functionB()
```

---

**Update 2: @Wilhelm Olejnik solved it by using an additional `BehaviorSubject`**

Comment: Look at the concat or concatMap operators for this.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example why `concat` doesn't work. (Or at least doesn't work with how I used it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand everything correctly you want to delay `getObservableB` execution until some observable will be assigned to property `observableA$`.

Maybe it is doable with some `Proxy` trick but I think it's easier to change `observableA$` into null-initialized `BehaviorSubject`. Then you can observe `observableA$` and create `observableB$` when non-null signal will be emitted.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-mm2edy

```js
import { of, BehaviorSubject, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, switchMap, mapTo, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const getObservableA = () => timer(100).pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('getObservableA')),
  mapTo('A')
);

const getObservableB = () => timer(100).pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('getObservableB')),
  mapTo('B')
);

class Test {
  // init observableA$ as BehaviorSubject with null state
  observableA$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  observableB$;


  functionA() {
    getObservableA().subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val)
      this.observableA$.next(val);      // notify subscribers that observableA$ is ready
    });
  }

  functionB() {
    this.observableB$ = this.observableA$.pipe(
      filter(value => value !== null),            // ignore observableA$ until initalized
      switchMap(value => getObservableB())
    )
    this.observableB$.subscribe(console.log)
  }
}

const test = new Test();

test.functionB();
setTimeout(() => test.functionA(), 500);

// getObservableA
// A
// getObservableB
// B
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much. `BehaviorSubject` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation in which I created a service `SyncService` to synchronize the observables. For me, `ObsA` and `ObsB` were coming from separate components. `ComponentA` got some initialization data that was needed by `ComponentB` after it loaded its own data.

In `ComponentA` I subscribed to `ObsA` (returned from `getInitData()`) and called into the sync service:

```
public initialize() {
   this.apiSvc.getInitData().subscribe((initData) => {
      this.data = initData;
      this.syncService.setA(initData);
   }
}
```

Then, in `ComponentB` I subscribe to `ObsB` (return from `getBData()`), and then subscribe to the sync service:

```
public loadBData() {
    this.apiSvc.getBData().subscribe((dataB) => {
        this.syncService.setB(dataB).subscribe((dataA, dataB) => {
            this.doStuffWithAAndB(dataA, dataB);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the sync service looks like this:

```
@Injectable
export class SyncService {
    private dataA: DataA = null;
    private dataB: DataB = null;
    private gotAEvent: new EventEmitter<DataA>();

    public setA(dataA: DataA) {
        this.dataA = dataA;
        if (this.dataB != null) {
            // ObsB was already resolved!
            this.gotAEvent.emit(dataA);
        }
    }

    public setB(dataB: DataB) {
        this.dataB = dataB;
        if (this.dataA != null) {
            return of({this.dataA, this.dataB});
        } else {
            return this.gotAEvent().map((dataA: DataA) => {
                return {dataA, dataB};
            }
        }
    }
}
```